# Python subsample with certain attributes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, sampling

I'd would like to create a subsample out of dataset whilst keeping some aggregate measures within certain boundaries.

For example - I want to draw 10% of rows and keep the average attribute X within certain boundaries.

This is in fact stratification. I am working in Python and usually use `StratifiedShuffleSplit`, but I have no idea if this can be somehow used in my case.

Comment: What is `StratifiedShuffleSplit`? If you're using a library you need to tag it.